# nginx error: openat() failed (20: not a directory) for images

Tags: php, api, nginx, server

I have a PHP project, a REST API. Nginx configuration is working for the API but is not for uploaded images

Images are always returning 404 error

the project starts at **/public** directory, upload directory is inside public, so the image access url is something like:

**DOMAIN.COM/upload/201812/20181204133821.jpg**

The actual NGINX configuration is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    set $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/html/api/public';
    root $root_path;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name api-eduplus.blanco-estudio.com;

    #try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
        root $root_path;
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    #error_log logs/error.log warn;
}
```

So the API starts at **/public** directory and images are uploaded into **/public/upload/**

Also. The nginx error log on the server says:

```
2018/12/04 16:35:54 [error] 17338: *1 openat() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/public/upload/201812/20181204133821.jpg" failed (20: Not a directory), request: "GET /upload/201812/20181204133821.jpg HTTP/1.1"
```

Please help, I'm actually stuck

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the requested file exist? Do you have problems uploading or downloading files?

Comment: @NicoHaase The file exists. The server returns a 404 error when downloading the file

Comment: And the file exists at that very position with proper permissions?

Comment: @NicoHaase Exists at that very position. I've already changed permissions for the file to test . 644, 744, 755, 775, 777.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue on my server. The cause of the error was a symlink.

I just encountered this (not very elucidating) error message on my server's nginx config:

```
"/path/to/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory)
```

After some trial-and-error, I determined that the actual cause was that nginx couldn't access the site's document root because part of the path to the `root` included a symlink, but I had `disable_symlinks on;` set in my main `nginx.conf` file.

Commenting-out the `disable_symlinks on;` line or changing it to `disable_symlinks off;` fixes the issue.

See also:

- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks